# How to make cat not print anything if the folder is empty

Tags: bash, cat

I'm working on bash, and my assignment is to print out all the files in the last modified subfolder and I can only use one line of commands.
This is what I've got so far:

```
cat "$( ls -t | head -1)"/*.*
```

This is working properly, except if the latest modified folder is empty, in which case cat returns an error. I need to avoid this and have cat print out nothing at all.

Comment: `cat "$(ls -t | head -1)" 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! In the future, indent your code by four spaces. That will make the stars show because it prevents all other special formatting. I fixed it for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

Consider redirecting standard error to `/dev/null`. This will cause any error messages that the command produces to be sent somewhere other than standard out. If your `cat` throws an error, the message would be sent to somewhere else, `/dev/null` to ignore it or some file if you wanted to log it. Your command would look something like:

```
cat "$( ls -t | head -1)"/*.* 2> /dev/null
```

The `2` represents standard error so `2>` is directing it to the location specified after.

Answer (score 0):

2>/dev/null
 This error re-direction will re-direct all error messages to a dump which can't be recovered,

use command 2> /dev/null